# How to temporarily change a setting in VSCode

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

When I am editing a standalone Python file in VSCode (not part of a workspace) I will often need to alter the value of `python.pythonPath` to reflect a specific virtualenv I am using to run that code.

As the setting is just for the one file, I don't want to change my persistent global settings, and I don't have workspace settings. Is there a way to change a setting just for this session? (Ideally, just for this one file, but I don't expect that to be possible, so I'd be happy with "just for the session"). If there isn't a built in way to do this, is there an extension which allows this? Or even an extension API that I could use to write my own extension for this?

As an alternative, is there a way to use an environment variable in a setting, and then set that environment variable for the current VSCode process? That would have the same effect, it would just require me to set up my user settings specifically to allow this usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch vscode from the terminal after having activated your virtualenv, vscode will automatically use the aforementioned virtualenv (with no modification to your settings):

Exemple:

```
source venv/bin/activate
code .
```

*Note*: if vscode is already opened, use `code -n .` in order to open the file/folder in a new window.

Comment: I tested that and it didn't (for me). I already had code open, and I did "code x.py" after activating a virtalenv. `x.py` was opened in the existing instance of code, and running it did *not* use the virtualenv.

Comment: have you tried launching a new vscode window ? In terminal, use `code -n .`

Comment: That does seem to work, so that's a good workaround. Thanks for that. I'd still like to be able to change this from within VSCode, though (I'm bound to forget the `-n` flag fairly often).